# Commands to extract data from a polyhedron?

Tags: polyhedra, geogebra

Suppose I have an entity in GeoGebra that is a polyhedron, but suppose that I don't know (have easy access to) the details of its construction (maybe it is some transformation of an original polyhedron, like a translation/mirror/rotation, etc.). Are there any commands I can use to extract information about it, like its vertices or centroid in 3D? When I have a polygon `p` that similarly I don't know the construction details for, I can execute `Vertex(p)` to get its vertices and `Centroid(p)` to get its centroid in its plane, but neither of those two commands will operate on a polyhedron. Are there any alternatives that will?

The only command I can find that seems to operate in general on polyhedra is `Volume()` but that gives me no information about the location of the polyhedron or any of its subelements, which is what I am trying to access.